# Can't seem to get element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria

I have a list of images and I really need to get ID of each image inside my JS, but I don't know how to do that. I've tried this method, but it is returning empty string instead of ID. I tried getting it from DOM elements http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/references/dom/  like `$(".galleria-thumbnails img").click(function(){alert((this).id)});` but this method is not working, alert is simply not showing up. Also I did some research here http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/api/methods/ and got this code, but this is showing alert of empty string.

```
    $("#gallery").galleria({
        });
    myGalleria = Galleria.get(0);

    myGalleria.$('thumbnails').click(function(){
        alert((this).id);
    });
```

gallery div

```
    <div id="gallery">
        <img id="someid" src="http://photoapproaches.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/helen-model-2272.jpg" />
        <img id="otherid" src="http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/photos/image1.jpg" />
    </div>
```

Console is empty of errors, nothing is showing in console. Also this markup is working fine the gallery plugin is making DOM elements on their own, and that is very frustrating with this situation. DOM structure can be viewed here, but I will link it in here as well http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/references/dom/

```
<div class="galleria-container">
    <div class="galleria-stage">
        <div class="galleria-images">
            <div class="galleria-image">
                <img>
            </div>
            <div class="galleria-image">
                <img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="galleria-loader"></div>
        <div class="galleria-counter">
            <span class="current"></span>
            <span class="total"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="galleria-image-nav">
            <div class="galleria-image-right-nav"></div>
            <div class="galleria-image-left-nav"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="galleria-thumbnails-container [ carousel ]">
        <div class="galleria-thumb-nav-left [ disabled ]"></div>
        <div class="galleria-thumbnails-list">
            <div class="galleria-thumbnails">
                <div class="galleria-image">
                    <img>
                </div>
                [...]
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="galleria-thumb-nav-right [ disabled ]"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="galleria-info">
        <div class="galleria-info-text">
            <div class="galleria-info-title"></div>
            <div class="galleria-info-description"></div>
            <div class="galleria-info-author"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="galleria-tooltip"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you get any error in Firebug/Webkit Console?

Comment: Based on your code, you're either missing or not showing us some of your markup. What is Galleria referring to? Or thumbnails - neither of those have any representation in your markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a one way to access id of an element:

```
 var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
```

For your case, you can try this:

```
myGalleria.$('thumbnails').click(function(){  

alert($(this).attr('id'));     

});
```

Comment: More like `this.id`, amirite? EDIT: sorry I see there is a whole discussion of this in the comments of the other answer...

Comment: Okey, right. Now I see "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'attr'" in console, but nothing of course is happening, no alert.

Comment: attr() is a standard method using jquery. check this out: http://api.jquery.com/attr                                  it could be that jquery js file is not loaded properly? If you use Firebug you can track the error.

Comment: When I use $(this).attr('id') it is not showing anything, when I use (this).attr('id') it is showing error. Makes perfect sense since I'm not using jQuery if I am not adding $ sign at the beginning. Well I will try to somehow get filename instead of ID. Probably it will be more likely possible.

Answer (score -2):

should it not be `alert($(this).id);`? (Note the `$`).

Comment: Then it is alerting "undefined"

Comment: `(this).id` and `this.id` are both correct. I believe `$(this).id` will not work at all. It returns `undefined`

Comment: It depends whether you want to do this with jQuery or with pure JS. With jQuery you do `$(this).attr('id')` and with pure JS you do `this.id`.

Comment: @Cokegod: But never `$(this).id`